# Assistance needed on Error 91 : Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to use the below given procedure to download unique mails but getting error (91 Object variable or with block variable not set) 
Error in line :   .`FindFirst "task =""" & Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID") & """"`

```vb
Private Sub getml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application

Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dealer As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set inbox = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
Set inboxItems = inbox.Items
For Each Mailobject In inboxItems

    With rst
        .FindFirst "task =""" & Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID") & """"
        If .NoMatch
            .AddNew
            !task= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
            !tsktml= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("timeline")
            .Update

            Mailobject.UnRead = False
        End If
    End With
End If
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set inbox = Nothing
Set inboxItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: i have tried to debug the code and figured out an error. The variant var shows null value after searching all the mails. i.e var returns the taskid till the last mail but after searching the last mail instead of exiting the for statement code loops the mail again and shows error. So I think I need to apply an exit for can you help me out in applying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error refers to some bug in your recordset object (it either isn't set appropriately, or has been closed before the `.FindFirst` runs).

I can't replicate it using the code you provided, so you will  need to troubleshoot this yourself.

You can often get more descriptive errors by removing the `With` block:

```vb
For Each Mailobject In inboxItems
    rst.FindFirst "task =""" & Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID") & """"
    If rst.NoMatch
        rst.AddNew
        rst!task= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
        rst!tsktml= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("timeline")
        rst.Update

        Mailobject.UnRead = False
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
```

by

```
Set rst= db.OpenRecordset("mls")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is how I have handled the error

```
Private Sub getml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application

Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim var As variant 
Set db = CurrentDb

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set inbox = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
Set inboxItems = inbox.Items
On error resume next
For Each Mailobject In inboxItems
   set var = MailObject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
IF Not (var Is Nothing) Then
       With rst 
           .FindFirst "task=" Chr(34) & var & Chr(34)
        If .NoMatch then
            .AddNew
            !task= var.value & ""
            .Update

            Mailobject.UnRead = False
        End If
    End With
End If
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set inbox = Nothing
Set inboxItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
End sub
```